# Something misleading about API Gateway CORS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors

As you can see below, I've selected "Enable CORS" under API Gateway, which apparently has configured the endpoint for CORS successfully without any errors:

[image]

However, when I try to POST to this endpoint, I'm left with the following error:

[image]

It seems like API Gateway is incorrect and that CORS is not actually enabled. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to manually fix this particularly because no errors are being thrown on the AWS side of things. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Happy to provide more information as necessary.

Comment: Did you create a new API deployment after enabling CORS? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY FOUND THE ANSWER. For whatever ridiculous reason, you need to navigate to Gateway Responses in API Gateway and set CORS for 4xx and 5xx responses and then redeploy. Here is a picture of what it should look like:[image]

I'm going to take a moment to get on a pedestal and point out how ridiculously counterintuitive it is for a user to hit "Enable CORS" and get a message back saying "CORS is successfully enabled!" when in reality it's not at all. AWS truly is the clunkiest of the existing cloud platforms.